Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada en Google Maps
Estoy usando el plugin 'locate and filter' en mi sitio web, y muestra solamente el mapa sin marcadores. El error que me arroja es "Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null)." Hace unos días estaba funcionando correctamente
